# how can I get mouseover to stay active once pointer leaves link with out clicking the link

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please review this link, http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xDaL8/1/
the code is perfect just need to now how can i get the link i rollover to stay in it's place so the view can read the side content and click on view more under the content for that particular link that was hovered over.

Updated:

when you roll over the left side which is the link the right side image and content changes which each hover on each link. the problem is you can click on "View More" on the right side under the content because once you take the pointer off the link it goes back to default, which is fine when you enter the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but don't you simply want to remove the mouseout function that resets the content?

ala:  http://jsfiddle.net/xDaL8/4/

Comment: when you roll over the left side which is the link the right side image and content changes which each hover on each link. the problem is you can click on "View More" on the right side under the content because once you take the pointer off the link it goes back to default, which is fine when you enter the site.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin called Firebug allows you to force the mouseover event on document elements without the mouse actually having to remain over the element.

Comment: I will like to have Jquery, Css coding, I seams that firebug is not for all browsers.

Comment: It is actually for most browsers.